# type.GetMethod returns nothing on newly instantiated entity linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, vb.net, reflection, linq-to-sql

I have an entity:

`var sf = context.GetSearchFilter(id);`

```
public partial class SearchFilter {
        public void DoWork(Type t) {
            // When sfc.Process() is called with this SearchFilterCriteria,
            // the problem occurs.  The method cannot be found.
            this.SearchFilterCriterias.Add(new SearchFilterCriteria() { SearchFilter = this }); // other properties added for processing, but irrelevant for this case
            foreach(var sfc in this.SearchFilterCriterias) { // SearchFilterCriterias are child entities of SearchFilter
                 sfc.Process(t);
            }
        }
    }

public partial class SearchFilterCriteria {
    public void Process(Type t) {
        var mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("Process" + t.Name);
        // mi is null when this SearchFilterCriteria is newly added
    }
}
```

For SearchFilterCriterias that are not pulled from the database as related entities, the method cannot be found.
    mi is null in Process();

Note: The method exists.

Anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish?  The `Getmethod` method will try to find a method of the class with the name you specify.  In this case you are specifying a method name of "Process" + t.Name.  Whether or not it finds one is dependent on the value of t.Name.  So if t.Name == "Foo", then your code will be attempting to find a method called `ProcessFoo`.  Does your class have a method named `ProcessFoo` where Foo is the value of t.Name?

Comment: The method exists.  t.Name can vary, but the method exists for t.Name in all cases, including the one that is causing the issue.

Comment: Well, `Type.GetMethod` disagrees. Can you verify through `this.GetType().GetMethods()` that your method is really there? And have you verified what `t` really is?

Comment: Is the method public or static. If so you may need to use the overload `var mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("Process" + t.Name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
`

Comment: Thanks @LasseV.Karlsen for the type to check GetMethods.  Turns out the method I was trying to call was declared wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I simply had my method declared incorrectly.